# MS detour MakeFile error

Tags: makefile, installation, visual-studio-2015, detours

I downloaded Detour Express 3.0 via MS (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)

My PC use `Intel i3 CPU` and `Windows 7 32bit`.

In addition, I use `Visual Studio 2015 Community`.

To install detour, I run `Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt`.

And do `NMAKE`(with all option)

Then the error occurs.

=========================================

(Error is written in Korean. I translated it myself)

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(1544): warning C4091: 'typedef ': 변수를 선언하지 않으면 '' 왼쪽은 무시됩니다.
```

C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(1544): warning C4091: 'typedef ': If you do not define variable, left side of '' will be ignored.

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(3190): warning C4091: 'typedef ': 변수를 선언하지 않으면 '' 왼쪽은 무시됩니다.
```

C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\dbghelp.h(3190): warning C4091: 'typedef ': If you do not define variable, left side of '' will be ignored.

What's wrong, and what should I do?

====additional information ===

In `Windows Kits` folder, there are 4 folders. `8.0, 8.1, 10, NETFXSDK`

I think this `Windows Kits` folder was installed when I installed `VS 2015`

Does it have any relationship with the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can lower remove treating warnings as errors /WX (project properties:c/c++:general. Or you can just manually delete the word typedef in the dbghelp.h at the two places the compiler flagged.